# Gulp/Browserify Error

Tags: gulp, browserify

I'm new to node and trying to setup browserify with gulp as per this tutorial: https://www.learnhowtoprogram.com/javascript/introduction-to-javascript/using-browserify-with-gulp. Please help I've tried googling, no solution.

My gulp file shows:

```
var gulp  = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
gulp.task('jsBrowserify', function() {
  return browserify({ entries: ['./js/pingpong-interface.js'] })
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('app.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/js'));
});
```

I ran in terminal:

```
gulp jsBrowserify
```

this should create the 'build' folder.

Instead I get the error:

```
C:\Users\danrusu\Documents\Coding Docs\projects\pingpong>gulp jsBrowserify
(node:7728) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.
[11:04:15] Using gulpfile ~\Documents\Coding Docs\projects\pingpong\gulpfile.js
[11:04:15] Starting 'jsBrowserify'...

events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
 SyntaxError: Unexpected token
```

Answer (score 0):

the `browserify` call requires an `.on('error', callback)` pipe to catch errors, even if there is none. Usually, I define something like:

```
function handleError(message){
  // print the message to console
}
```

and then can do:

```
return browserify({...})
  .on('error', handleError)
  .pipe(...)
  ...
```

I might have the exact syntax wrong, but you can easily go through browserify's documentation to find the exact syntax and calls it needs.